# How to manually commit Kafka offset in Apache Beam at the end of specific doFun execution

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-beam, kafka-consumer-api

I create a simple Apache Beam streaming pipeline which read data from Kafka, do some processing and persist the result by calling some external service's API. I want to make sure no data are lost during pipeline restart or failure so I want to manually commit the record offset to Kafka after I successfully call the API at the end of specific doFun execution.

In my previous Kafka experience, I know that by using Kafka Consumer's below API, I am able to manually commit the record offset to Kafka.

```
consumer.commitSync(currentOffsets);
```

There is setting to turn off the auto commit in KafkaIO setup, however I didn't find any working solution to manually commit offset in Apache Beam as there seems no way I can access the consumer in doFun. Appreciated if some expert can share some hint with sample codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `pipeline.apply(KafkaIO.read()...)` will return a `PCollection<KafkaRecord<K, V>>`. So, downstream in your pipeline you can get an offset from `KafkaRecord` metadata and commit it manually in a way that you need (just don't forget to disable AUTO_COMMIT in `KafkaIO.read()`).

Though, you need to make sure that a call to external API and offset commit will be atomic to prevent potential data loss (if it's critical).

Comment: "commit it manually in a way that you need", can you kindly share some sample code for commit offset within a Beam doFun? The problem I am facing is that I don't know how to access the kafka consumer in a doFun, appreciated if any hint!

Comment: By manual way, I mean that you should instantiate your own Kafka client in your DoFn, process input element (as `KafkaRecord<K, V>`), that was read before, fetch an offset from `KafkaRecord` and commit it with your own client.

Comment: Is my below understanding correct? Currently Apache Beam framework itself 
 doesn't provide a way to commit offset manually but we can use a workaround to create a Kafka Consumer in doFun which attach to the same topic as KafkaIO do and commit the offset ourselves.

Comment: Yes, in your specific case, you need to use `KafkaIO` only to read messages. To commit the offsets manually in a way that you need later you need to use own Kafka client in your `DoFn`